# General approach to finding the laurent expansion of f(x)

Tags: complex-analysis

> Expand the following function in a Laurent series in the indicated
>   domain:

$$
f(x) = (z-1)/z^2 \quad  \text{in the domain} \quad |z-1|>1
$$

So far I have:

$$
(z-1) \times \frac{1}{(z-1)^2} = \frac{1}{(z-1)}
$$

A hint would help and thanks

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer following an update to the question:

You need to find a power series of $(z-1)$. A common technique is to rewrite your function in the form of functions whose power series you already know but using $(z-1)$ instead of $z$.
For $f(z) = \frac{z-1}{z^2}$ the numerator is already in the right form. The problematic part is the denominator. If you can represent $\frac{1}{z}$ as a power series in $(z-1)$ you can multiply it by the numerator and get your final series.
Note that you are looking for a series that converges in $|z-1| \gt 1$ and therefore $\Big| \frac{1}{z-1} \Big| \lt 1$ and you can rewrite the denominator like this:
$$
\frac{1}{z^2} = \frac{1}{(1+z-1)^2} = \frac{1}{(z-1)^2}\cdot\frac{1}{(1-(-\frac{1}{z-1}))^2}
$$

You should be able to expand this to a power series based on:
$$\frac{1}{(1-w)^2} = 1 + 2w + 3w^2 + \dots \space \text{, for } |w| \lt 1$$
which is derived from $\frac{1}{1-w}$ by term-by-term differentiation

Comment: Sorry I just corrected the edit: its (z-1)/z^2

Comment: what I did was \frac{z-1}{(z-1)^2} = \frac{1}{z-1} my problem is where to proceed from there?

Comment: please see my updated answer based on your edits. I tried to be more detailed in how to approach this kind of questions. does that help?

Comment: that was helpful : I got 1/(z-1)-2/(z-1)^2+3/(z-1)^3-... and thanks

Comment: in general: 1- check to see if you need to make a substitution for the region you are working with,  a substitute if the region is not centered on z = 0.                                                         2) manipulate the function into a form where you can use the series may involve splitting by partial fractions.                                                           3)Then find the series expansions for each of the fractions you have in your function within the specied region, then substitute these back into your function

Comment: having stated step 3). What if after splitting your function into two and the domain a<|z|<b. For the first fraction domain |z|>a is valid but |z|<b isn't valid(that is it is outside of the region)? What do I do?

Comment: if $a \lt |z| \lt b$ and you find a series that converges in $|z| \gt a$ then it also converges in $a \lt |z| \lt b$